# removeProp not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the max property from a date field on my webpage. Depending on the fields selected before the date field the max may be set to today or there may not be one. In one of my scenarios, I am trying to remove the max and it works and in another it doesn't. See details below.

Using Google Chrome

**Working**

```
$('#StartDate').removeProp('max');
console.log(document.getElementById('StartDate'));
```

Copy element using developer tools

```
<input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class=" wf2_isBlank wf2_notDefaultValue wf2_lostFocus" min="" max="undefined" required="">
```

Picture of element in console
[image]

**Not Working**

```
$('#StartDate').removeProp('max');
console.log(document.getElementById('StartDate'));
```

Copy element using developer tools

```
<input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class=" wf2_isBlank wf2_notDefaultValue" required="" max="2018-08-20" min="">
```

Picture of element in console
[image]

What is the difference here? Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your code snippets are the same, and also your images of the console are the same.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading something correctly, but I don't see any difference between the code that does and does not work. Nor do I see a difference between the images. Could you specify what you mean by "not working" and maybe provide some context on how it's called?

Comment: yes the code is written the same, but it 2 different functions. Any reason why one would would work and the other wouldn't?

Comment: It's not two different functions, unless you mean it's being run in two different functions? It's still rather a mystery as to what your issue really is..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use removeAttr to remove attribute from element

```js
$('input').removeAttr('max');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class=" wf2_isBlank wf2_notDefaultValue" required="" max="2018-08-20" min="">
```

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/